# How to implement a graph with node specific calculations in Python?

Tags: python, tree

I am trying to implement something similar to a tree. There are base nodes (data input) and calculated nodes (these can be based on both base nodes and calculated nodes).
As a node can have multiple parents, it's not a tree anymore.

Basically, the value of a computed node is the sum or product of its children. But it can also be a much more complex calculation (root, power, etc. and various combinations).
*Problem one*: for special computations the code of the class must be adapted in each case and the computation function must be adapted.

I had tried the following:

```
import numpy as np

class Node:
    def __init__(self, node_id, calc = 'sum'):
        
        self.id = node_id
        self.calc = calc
        self.children = set([])
        self.val = np.nan
        
    def add_child(self, c_id): self.children.add(c_id)
    def get_val(self): return self.val
    def set_val(self, value): self.val = value
    
    def calc_node(self):
        if bool(self.children):
            if self.calc == 'sum':
                val = 0
                for child in self.children:
                    val += child.get_val()
            elif self.calc == 'prod':
                val = 1
                for child in self.children:
                    val *= child.get_val()
            elif self.calc == 'calc_3':
                val = all_nodes['raw_1'].get_val() * \
                            all_nodes['raw_3'].get_val() + \
                            all_nodes['calc_1'].get_val()
            self.val = val

all_nodes = {'raw_1': Node('raw_1'),'raw_2': Node('raw_2'),
            'raw_3': Node('raw_3'),
            'calc_1': Node('calc_1', 'prod'),'calc_2': Node('calc_2'),
            'calc_3': Node('calc_3','calc_3')}

all_nodes['raw_1'].set_val(10.0)
all_nodes['raw_2'].set_val(5.0)
all_nodes['raw_3'].set_val(2.5)

all_nodes['calc_1'].add_child(all_nodes['raw_1'])
all_nodes['calc_1'].add_child(all_nodes['raw_2'])
all_nodes['calc_1'].calc_node()

all_nodes['calc_2'].add_child(all_nodes['raw_1'])
all_nodes['calc_2'].add_child(all_nodes['raw_2'])
all_nodes['calc_2'].calc_node()

#children of calc_3 are only relevant to determine children
all_nodes['calc_3'].add_child(all_nodes['raw_3'])
all_nodes['calc_3'].add_child(all_nodes['calc_1'])
all_nodes['calc_3'].add_child(all_nodes['calc_2'])
all_nodes['calc_3'].calc_node()

print(all_nodes['calc_1'].get_val())
print(all_nodes['calc_2'].get_val())
print(all_nodes['calc_3'].get_val())
```

*Problem two*: the class uses the global variable `all_nodes`. This could be solved by defining `self.children` as an ordered set. Or are there better solutions?

The first problem can be solved by simply incorporating the basic arithmetic operations including power, root, etc. and adding an extra node (intermediate node which calculates the product used in `calc_2`). But with a complex calculation, this can quickly become confusing. Are there other possibilities here? Or does it make sense to use a string as `self.calc` and use `eval()` to calculate the value? I assume this is not a good coding style and might be slow if there are huge numbers of nodes.

In perspective, I want to integrate the calculation into a GUI (Tkinter? PyQt5?) where I can define nodes myself without having to customize the code. If you say this doesn't make sense and a code-only solution makes more sense, then I'll focus on the code-only solution.

Since I am new to object-orientated programming, I would appreciate any advice or similar examples. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1 can be solved via passing a function as an argument to the constructor. Since everything in python is an object, functions can passed into an object and set as an attribute without issue.

Problem 2, It really depends on how you want to use the class. If you want to be able to access any node at any point from the ID, then you would want a dictionary. If only need to calculate the value of the bottom of the tree then you don't need any system really and you can just leave the higher nodes somewhere in the children of the lower nodes.

Also I would recommend using a system where calling get_val attempts to evaluate the value of its children recursively so that you don't need to manually evaluate each Node.

```
import numpy as np

def sum_child(children): return sum([x.get_val() for x in children])

class Node:
   def __init__(self, calc=sum_child):
      self.calc_node = calc
      self.children = set([])

   def get_val(self):
      try :
         return self.val
      except AttributeError:
         return self.calc_node(self.children)

   def add_child(self, child):
      self.children.add(child)

raw_1 = Node(lambda self: 10)
raw_2 = Node(lambda self: 5)
raw_3 = Node(lambda self: 2.5)

def product(children):
   val = 1
   for child in children :
      val *= child.get_val()
   return val
      
calc_1 = Node(product)
calc_2 = Node()

calc_1.add_child(raw_1)
calc_1.add_child(raw_2)

calc_2.add_child(raw_1)
calc_2.add_child(raw_2)

print(calc_1.get_val())
print(calc_2.get_val())
```

Here is my attempt at this system. I wasn't really sure what you were trying to do with calc_3 since it wasn't actually based on the child nodes and always resolved to a constant so I just left it out.

Comment: Didn't know how to implement it. ```calc_3 = Node(child_calc3)``` would be like ```def child_calc3(children): return children[0].get_val()*children[1].get_val()+children[2].get_val()``` where the children are stored in a list ```self.children = list()``` and the children are added in the specific order.